# Xcode UI Test How to handle notification permissions generated by UNUserNotificationCenter

Tags: swift, xcode, uitest

In my app, I ask for notification permissions like this:

```
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in

        if granted {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        }
    }
```

Now while testing, I need to handle this permission popup but it is not working, I tried these code:

```
XCUIApplication().alerts["“AppName” Would Like to Send You Notifications"].buttons["Allow"].tap() //didn't work.

addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription("Notification Dialog") { (alert) -> Bool in  
    alert.buttons["Allow"].tap()
    return true
}


addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription("“AppName” Would Like to Send You Notifications") { (alert) -> Bool in  
    alert.buttons["Allow"].tap()
    return true
}


addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription("Notifications may include alerts, sounds, and icon badges. These can be configured in Settings.") { (alert) -> Bool in  
    alert.buttons["Allow"].tap()
    return true
}
```

But nothing works.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
    let app2 = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")
    let button = app2.alerts.firstMatch.buttons["Allow"]
    button.waitForExistence(timeout: 10)
    button.tap()
```

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks. For some reason, system dialogues are no longer a part of the app? iOS 14.4, Xcode 12.4

Comment: UIInterruptionHandler also works. You have to add app.tap() after the interruption handler block to make it work. But as Apple suggests, it should be used only for alerts which you have no idea when they will occur.

Comment: I'm getting this error when I use this approach, on the `tap()` call:
`[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil (NSInvalidArgumentException)`

Comment: @rmp251 Xcode is broken and I don't see any way to sort that. That's a disaster.

Comment: @PedroPauloAmorim agreed. Almost unusable.

Comment: @rmp251 I managed to skip this issue for only using the simulator on iOS 15.4.

Comment: @rmp251 Restarting the iOS device helped me resolve the issue

Comment: This solution didn't work for me. It can't find the Notification permission alert and allow buttons..

Answer (score 0):

I used the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/users/7680493/mohamed-wasiq but the problem still exists. I used his solution and changed it to:

```
let app2 = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")
app2.alerts.firstMatch.buttons.firstMatch.tap()
```

This worked for me very fine, both lines must be used, without the first I am not able to access system dialogs and the second line does not seem to find the buttons. So I used the first button, because I did not need the permission inside the tests. I think there will also be solutions to access the other one by indexing or something.

Answer (score -2):

1/ Try recording the path with XCode test recorder to alert button and make sure, you have the right one.

```
XCUIApplication().alerts["“AppName” Would Like to Send You Notifications"].buttons["Allow"].tap() //didn't work.
```

might not be correct.

(note: Using test recorder for things, like finding the path to element is ok and very newbie-friendly.)

2/ You don't have to use `addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription` in case, you have a system alert that will happen every time or in case, you know that it will happen. 
Just use `waitForExistance` and tap it if it exists.

(note: I've found that waiting & tapping on system notification is better than `addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription`, which is unstable/complicated sometimes)

3/ `alert.buttons["Allow"].tap()` doesn't seem to be correct to me, shouldn't it be `XCUIApplication().alerts.buttons["Allow"]`? Alternatively, you can use `XCUIApplication().alerts.buttons.element(boundBy: 0` to tap on first button.

Answer (score -2):

```
import XCTest

// For multiple permission requests
var isPhotoPermissionAvailable: Bool?
var isLocationPermissionAvailable: Bool?
var isNotificationsPermissionAvailable: Bool?

extension XCTestCase {

    func allowPhotos(_ enabled: Bool = true) {
        addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "Photo Permissions") { (alert) -> Bool in
            isPhotoPermissionAvailable = enabled
            var alertButton = alert.buttons["Don't Allow"]
            if enabled == true {
                alertButton = alert.buttons["OK"]
            }
            if alertButton.exists {
                alertButton.tap()
                return true
            }
            XCUIApplication().tap()
            return false
        }
        if isPhotoPermissionAvailable == nil {
            XCUIApplication().swipeUp() //with this code, alert.buttons["OK"] exsists
        }
    }

    func allowLocation(_ enabled: Bool = true) {
        addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "Location Dialog") { (alert) -> Bool in
            isLocationPermissionAvailable = enabled
            var alertButton = alert.buttons["Don't Allow"]
            if enabled == true {
                alertButton = alert.buttons["Always Allow"]
            }
            if alertButton.exists {
                alertButton.tap()
                return true
            }
                XCUIApplication().tap()
            return false
        }
        if isLocationPermissionAvailable == nil {
            XCUIApplication().swipeUp()
        }
    }

    func allowNotifications(_ enabled: Bool = true) {
        addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "Notification Dialog") { (alert) -> Bool in
            isNotificationsPermissionAvailable = enabled
            var alertButton = alert.buttons["Don't Allow"]
            if enabled == true {
                alertButton = alert.buttons["Allow"]
            }
            if alertButton.exists {
                alertButton.tap()
                return true
            }
            XCUIApplication().tap()
            return false
        }
        if isNotificationsPermissionAvailable == nil {
            XCUIApplication().swipeUp()
        }
    }
}
```